# Driver fails to switch back to previous page after the current page closes

Tags: automation, karate, ui-automation, gherkin

In my web application, when the homepage is open and I click on a link, a different webpage gets opened.
This switch is successful using switchPage('title'); however, when the opened page gets closed and I am trying to switch back to previous web page using "switchPage('title')", it fails.

This issue was fixed according to below link in Karate 1.3.0, but I am still facing it:
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2032

Below is the code for your reference:

[image: Code snippet]

Can someone please assist me here?

I tried switchpage(null),(0),(-1), null and -1 worked but it failed in the next step.
Tried it in headless mode but not working.

Comment: every web page is different and JS can cause all kinds of behavior. I think your best bet is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue